# Send mail demo in laravel using default mail functionality of Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, send

I am new to laravel and start learning laravel. I have try many of posts for sending mail using laravel default functionality, but i am not able to send mail i got some error like "Class 'Illuminate\Mail\Mailable' not found". can anyone please give me guidance for sending mail or demo if anyone has available which is working properly. i am using laravel 5.2.45 and run in local xampp server. so do i need to make changes in configuration of xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to configure `.env` file for your email settings.

**add to Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

**Use Mail model**

```
$validator = [
  'name' => 'Darth Wader'
]; // this is where you will store data which will be passed to mail template;

$emailWhereToSend = demo@demo.co.uk

// demo.blade.php in views/emails folder 

Mail::send('emails.demo', ['data' => $validator], function ($m) use 
($validator, $emailWhereToSend) {
        $m->from('info@website.co.uk', 'Extra text From');
        $m->to($emailWhereToSend, $validator['name'])->subject($validator['name'].' Random Subject');
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. Its Working

Comment: I have accept as correct but my reputation is low so it could not show sorry

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the version you're using the Mailable class was not yet introduced into Laravel. I guess it started with Laravel 5.3, when you're using Laravel 5.2, so you need to do it the classic way, here is all you need:
[Laravel 5.2 Send mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail)

Comment: I have install laravel using command prompt so do i need to specify version at time of installation. or it install latest version itself

Comment: Normaly you should be able to install the last version if you didn't specify a version within composer way to install. Follow those instructions and you'll be good: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation